# lerna conventional versioning with github actions

Tags: github-actions, lerna, semantic-versioning, conventional-commits, conventional-changelog

I've setup the github actions to run on PRs against `development` and `main`. Then in the workflow I have a task as follow:

```sh
if [ ${{ github.base_ref }} = development ]; then
  npx lerna version --conventional-prerelease --preid beta --yes
else
  npx lerna version --conventional-graduate --yes
fi
```

Basically version a beta release, then publish `development` when a PR is against that branch while graduating the last beta release and publishing from `main` when PR is against `main` branch. This works great except when graduating a beta release, `development` maintains its last beta version while `main` bumps up to the graduated production version (e.g. `development` is 1.0.1-beta.0 while `main` is 1.0.1). There's also difference in the `CHANGELOG.md` content when graduating a beta version. This behavior causes `main` and `development` to get out of sync because the `CHANGELOG.md` and the production version in `main` never propagate into `development` branch. How do you fix this issue?

**Idea**

Merge `main` back into `development` after every beta graduation. This goes against the `git` flow.

Here's the `lerna.json`:

```json
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "conventionalCommits": true,
      "verifyAccess": false,
      "commitHooks": false,
      "ignoreChanges": [
        "*.md",
        "*(\\.|-)test.ts"
      ],
      "version": {
        "message": "chore(release): version and release commit"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you end up with a solution here?

Comment: @sargturner nope. I dropped the idea of having beta versions altogether.